# Google admob sdk 6.9.3 replacement on existing ios game

Tags: ios, admob

Trying to replace admob sdk in existing ios game, but it still logs the warning  message

> Google Mobile Ads SDK: You are currently using 6.4.2 of the SDK. A new
>   version, 6.9.2, is available at http://goo.gl/Zc0BYt . Please consider
>   updating your SDK to get the latest features and bug fixes

though i have updated admob ad unit id with the new one and replaced all admob sdk files, and also updated my admob account.
Does anyone has this issue before?

Comment: Yes! I am also getting same error though I have updated it through given link. Google had really updated that version or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing all instances of older admob sdk  from my mac, and clean and rebuild the projects again.
It seems that xcode reads admob library somewhere from the cache, so the clean and rebuild will help.
also do not forget to change the admob identifier with the new identifier standart, this is important otherwise you will get the message again.